# While trying to display wav file using scipi im getting the following error "ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to implement FFT, and after selecting blocklength I'm trying to play my audio file , but the error is popping up.
here is the following code-

```
IPython.display.Audio(data=data, rate=rate)
```

Error:

```
ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Try transposing the data, as mentioned on:
[scipy.io : can't write wavfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822877/scipy-io-cant-write-wavfile)

I had the same problem trying to play a sample after reading a wav file using scipy.io.wavfile.read(). Not sure if it's my processing that causes this, a quick fix is:

```
display(Audio(samples.T, rate=sampleRate))
```