# For mms-tts-eng model I am getting ushort format error

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

```
from transformers import VitsModel, AutoTokenizer
import torch

model = VitsModel.from_pretrained("facebook/mms-tts-eng")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/mms-tts-eng")

text = "some example text in the English language"
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")

with torch.no_grad():
  output = model(**inputs).waveform

import scipy
scipy.io.wavfile.write("techno.wav", rate=model.config.sampling_rate, 
data=output.cpu().float().numpy())
```

I am getting this:

```
error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (0x7fff * 2 + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825545) solved this issue for me. So simply transposing your waveform output should fix this.

So instead of doing this:

```py
import scipy
scipy.io.wavfile.write("techno.wav", rate=model.config.sampling_rate, 
data=output.cpu().float().numpy())
```

I did:

```py
import scipy
scipy.io.wavfile.write("techno.wav", rate=model.config.sampling_rate, 
data=output.cpu().float().numpy().T)
```